# Is it possible to initialize redux store once and use in multiple page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux store. Lets say the state is as `{names:[], address:[]}`. There are multiple pages and all use `names` and `address` as properties. However, I have to do `API` call in each page to fetch `names` and `address` which is increasing network traffic. Is there a workaround that will help in storing the values obtained in first API call and store for later uses, so that the values obtained can be reused without calling the API again?

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you propose in the question. You just need some way of knowing whether the information you need is already in the store.

Initialize your store with a flag set to false.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  names: [],
  address: [],
  upToDate: false
}
```

When you need to make your api call, check the flag. Simply skip if it's already true.

```
if (!this.props.exampleReducer.uptoDate) {
  // Make the api call
}
```

Finally you need to set the flag to true when you've done your api call.

```
...
case: 'API_CALL_SUCCESS':
  return {
    names: [ ... ],
    address: [ ... ],
    upToDate: true
  }
...
```

Comment: Is this approach usable across multiple files?Any reducer that was set from file1 should be available from file2.

Comment: You already have a redux store. The point of a redux store is that you can use it in any component you wish. If you're using the store correctly, you should already be able to use it across multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the store and import it in any file you wish:

```
// App.js
export const store = configureStore();

// any_file.js
import { store } from './../App';

...
store.dispatch(...);

store.getState()... ;
```